# For what values of $x$ is $[x]=2$? and the answer was $[2,3)$.

Tags: calculus

The example I saw was for what values of $x$ is $[x]=2$ and the answer was $[2,3)$. For me I got the question as for what values of $x$ is $[x]=6$ so my answer is $[6,7)$ but for some reason it is wrong. Can anyone help me figure out why or what is the right answer

Comment: The correct answer is $[6,7)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\lfloor x\rfloor$, the floor function?

Comment: @RushabhMehta it was similar to the fucntion u had but the line was at the top

Comment: Do you then mean $\lceil x \rceil$, usually used to refer to the ceiling function?

Comment: @CrostulI this is what i got but it gave me it as wrong that is why i was inquiring about it

Comment: @GoodDeeds yes it is the ceiling function

Comment: This is a good reminder that you should pay attention to exactly how things are drawn.  Minor differences in symbols used often mean that different functions are being used.  $\lfloor x\rfloor$ represents the floor of $x$ (*the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$*) while $\lceil x \rceil$ represents the ceiling of $x$ (*the least integer greater than or equal to $x$*).  $[x]$ is an alternate notation for floor that is sometimes in use, while $\{x\}$ is sometimes used to denote the "fractional part" of $x$.

Comment: In combinatorics, we have several closely related symbols used for different things: $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\r\end{smallmatrix}\right],\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\r\end{smallmatrix}\right\},\binom{n}{r},\left(\!\!\binom{n}{r}\!\!\right)$ all represent different things and noting the difference between them is important.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comment it is ceiling function 
$$\lceil x \rceil=6$$

Because of any number that is greater than 5 and less than equal to 6 ceil function will convert it to 6

Thus you get $$x\in (5,6]$$

Comment: Thank you! I was not taught about the ceiling and floor functions and so i did not know about it and I had a question assigned about it with the professor and he did not even teach us this.

Comment: ceil function is just opposite of floor